# Had been operative Vs had been operated

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives

What is the difference between **had been operative** and **had been operated**.

Example :

1. the machines had been operative at the premises.
2. the machines had been operated at the premises.

Would it be possible for both phrases to be used interchangeably to indicate that the machine was once used at the premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is no. You are asking the difference between 2 very different adjective.

Here you can understand what I mean: [differences between operative Vs Operational](https://wikidiff.com/operative/operational#:%7E:text=As%20adjectives%20the%20difference%20between,to%20operations%2C%20especially%20military%20operations.)

Anyway,for saying that the machine where used at least once at the premises you should use something like that:

> The machines were used on the premises **/** The machines were **operational** on the premises